# t test by using R studio:grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels error

Tags: r

[image]

I don't speak English well.
I am doing t test by using R studio, but I have a big problem.

error :grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

[image]

This data picture doesn't have all data, but value1 column have o ,x, NA. 
how can I solve this problem.

Comment: `DATA1 <- na.omit(DATA1)` to remove NAs

Answer (score 1):

Your problem description is incomplete in the data description. Please add the results of `str(DATA1)` and `summary(DATA1)` to further questions. Better yet, a minimal complete verifiable example.

Now, `t.test` is very well able to handle `NA`data. This will work without any problem.

```
a = rnorm(20)
b = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", NA, NA,
      "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", NA, NA)

t.test(a ~ b, var.equal=FALSE)
```

So the most likely problem is, that your missing data are not `NA` but a string as in `"NA"`.  You can check that like this:

```
> unique(b)
[1] "x" NA  "o"
```

As you can see, there are no `"` around NA and that is, what you are supposed to achieve. One possible way to do so:

```
wrong = c("x", "NA", "NA", "o", "o")
right = ifelse(wrong == "NA", NA, wrong)
print(right)
```

HTH